# How can I improve this JavaScript class?

Tags: javascript, oop

I'm new to JavaScript and I know my code is weird, how can I fix this? Also, how can I call a function within a function? I want to convert all the values to a number or a float and call the solution.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

    function Math(){                        

        var firstNumber = document.getElementById("firstnumber");
        var secondNumber = document.getElementById("secondnumber");

        this.add = function(){          
            var fN = Number( firstNumber.value );
            var sN = Number( secondNumber.value );
            return ( fN + sN );
        }

        this.sub = function(){          
            var fN = Number( firstNumber.value );
            var sN = Number( secondNumber.value );
            return ( fN - sN );
        }

        this.div = function(){          
            var fN = Number( firstNumber.value );
            var sN = Number( secondNumber.value );
            return ( fN - sN );
        }


        this.mul = function(){          
            var fN = Number( firstNumber.value );
            var sN = Number( secondNumber.value );
            return ( fN * sN );
        }

    }

    var myNewMath = new Math();         

</script>
```

Comment: we probably miss the html part to understand what you're doing. Is it some kind of calculator exercise?

Comment: What is the problem you encounter actually ?

Comment: There's already a name [`Math`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math) in JavaScript. Don't clobber it.

Answer (score 1):

The code isn't *too* bad at all for a beginner, if a little repetitive.

To keep things simple for now, I would probably do something like this to avoid the repeated calls to `Number(element.value)`:

```
function Calculator() { // NB: not "Math" - that's a standard object                   

    var firstNumber = document.getElementById("firstnumber");
    var secondNumber = document.getElementById("secondnumber");

    function op1() {
        return Number(firstNumber.value);
    }

    function op2() {
        return Number(secondNumber.value);
    }

    this.add = function() {          
        return op1() + op2();
    }

    this.sub = function() {
        return op1() - op2();
    }

    ...
}
```

Comment: +1 Probably worth noting that you'd want to use `new` when invoking.

Comment: @MatthewBlancarte the OP appear to already know that.

Comment: Oh, whoops, I didn't see the scrollbar on his code dump. You're totally right. :)

Comment: I would also consider adding the methods to `Calculator.prototype` instead of recreating them for every instance.

Comment: @benekastah depends on how many instances there are - there's no great overhead of adding functions like this when there's only one instance, which looks probable in this case.  In any event, prototype functions can't access the scoped variables in the constructor.